# Optimizar o mejorar algoritmo

Tags: python, algoritmos

**Saludos, tengo el siguiente ejercicio:
Elabore programa en Python que le permita al usuario ingresar números enteros de manera indefinida, hasta que ingrese
un número negativo, y al final imprimir la suma de los números enteros pares sin incluir el número negativo en la suma.**

```
numero = int(input("Escriba un número: "))
suma = 0
while numero > 0:
    numero = int(input("Escriba un número: "))
    if numero % 2 == 0 and numero > 0:
        suma += numero 
print(f"La suma de los números enteros pares {suma}.")
```

**El código en realidad funciona pero cuando lo ejecuto dentro del VPL me muestra que de los tres test solo dos corren bien, quizás me hace falta algo para mejorar. Pregunta: ¿Existe alguna manera de optimizar o mejorar el algoritmo?** [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no voy a a comentar sobre mejorar, no me gustan los exagerados puristas del código, eso siempre es personal, salvo que sea en optimizar velocidad, pero el planteo dice hasta que... número negativo, bueno debe ser menor que 0, éste es positivo

Comment: una cosa es optimizar el código (tiempo de ejecución, legibilidad, etc) y otra cosa es hallar el problema de tu codigo

Comment: Aún así creo que el error es bastante obvio y que si algunas veces le funciona el cálculo es porque coincide que el primer input que le dan es un número par.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, el titulo es mal lo que intenta hacer no es optimizar ni mejorar, esta intentando resolver un problema cuya solución la tiene parcialmente.

```
suma = 0
while True:
    numero = int(input("Escriba un número: "))
    if numero < 0:
        break
    
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        suma += numero 

print(f"La suma de los números enteros pares {suma}.")
```

En el código anterior como se desea hacer un bucle infinito se usa la palabra reservada `True` que como sabemos es un dato de tipo booleano, el bucle `while` así como los condicionales se evaluá una expresión y si el valor es verdadero ingresa al bloque interno de sentencias, entonces al usar `True` en la parte de la expresión a evaluar esta siempre será verdadera y ejecutara el bucle infinitamente a menos que se detenga por una Excepción (Error) o por uso de `break` (partir [salir]).

Comment: también se podría usar el operador morsa `:=`

Comment: @christian recuerda que el operador morsa esta desde Python 3.8. O sea si OP tiene Python 3.5, va a suceder un error de intentar usarlo.

Comment: @DanteS. Verdad, siempre se me pasa eso 